# mongod crash(terminated with signal 5)

Tags: mongodb, crash

I configured a  mongodb's capped collection,with capacity more than 3G,after that mongod crash for many times,but there was nothing wrong in the mongd.log.Howerver linux abrt has core dumped for mongod,messages from coredump are as following:

```
    Program terminated with signal 5, Trace/breakpoint trap. #0 0x00000000010b9951 in v8::internal::OS::DebugBreak() () Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install 
glibc-2.12-1.107.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.x86_64 (gdb) where #0 0x00000000010b9951 in v8::internal::OS::DebugBreak() () #1 0x00000000010ba06a in 
v8::internal::OS::Abort() () #2 0x0000000000f1c5f3 in API_Fatal(char const*, char const*, ...) () #3 0x0000000000ece607 in ?? () #4 0x0000000000ece916 in 
v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) () #5 0x000000000108c891 in v8::internal::Map::UpdateCodeCache(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, 
v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>) () #6 0x0000000001149180 in 
v8::internal::StubCache::ComputeKeyedLoadOrStoreElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::KeyedIC::StubKind, v8::internal::StrictModeFlag) () #7 
0x0000000001000bfc in v8::internal::KeyedIC::ComputeMonomorphicStub(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, 
v8::internal::KeyedIC::StubKind, v8::internal::StrictModeFlag, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>) () #8 0x000000000100779a in 
v8::internal::KeyedIC::ComputeStub(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::KeyedIC::StubKind, v8::internal::StrictModeFlag, 
v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>) () #9 0x0000000001008551 in v8::internal::KeyedLoadIC::Load(v8::internal::InlineCacheState, 
v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool) () #10 0x000000000100894d in v8::internal::KeyedLoadIC_Miss(v8::internal::Arguments, 
v8::internal::Isolate*) ()
```

my mongodb is 2.4.1, running in centos 6.3,16G memory and 8cpus.
Anyone can help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out of memory error mentioned makes me suspect that this could be an occurrence of this bug (V8 memory leaking):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9230

Can you upgrade to 2.4.2+ and see if the error still happens for you?

Comment: Thanks very much,I'll try to upgrade to 2.4.2+